# Fineuploader retrieve qquuid before actual post?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, upload, guid, fine-uploader

I'm using the jquery version of FineUploader v5.3, and chunk all my uploaded files.  Thanks for the help yesterday, and this is working nicely now.

Here's my current issue:

On the server I currently look at the qquuid within the Request and create a folder as necessary to house the temporary chunk files that are coming in.  This was originally designed when only 1 file was incoming, but now it's unnecessary code on the second and subsequent chunks (folder already exists, but index order of chunks is unknown).  Is there a way to determine the qquuid that will be used for the file within an event BEFORE the actual post so I can do the needed infrastructure? I tried using the OnSubmitted event, but all that I can get from here is the ID (chunk index) or the name.  Please let me know if you require any clarification.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

v3.5 is *incredibly* old - about 2.5 years old to be exact. Looking at [the API doc from that time](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/3.5.0/docs/api-fineuploaderbasic.md), I see that a `getUuid` method existed. If you pass in the file ID, you will be able to get a handle on the file's UUID. You can make this call in your `onSubmitted` callback handler.

Comment: Ah, I meant v5.3.  Sorry.

Comment: Same answer should apply to 5.3 if you're simply looking to find the UUID of a file.